# Delphi 11.1 Android app crashes after flash screen - no error compiling - worked fine in 10.4.2

Tags: android, delphi

There is something I am missing in migrating my app from Delphi 10.4.2 to Delphi 11.1. I did "revert system files" on the libraries as I have seen mentioned elsewhere, which eliminated errors. It compiles error-free but the code won't run on Android, crashing right after the splash screen. It happens in both Development and Application Store configurations and on multiple versions of Android on different devices, not just Android 11. Note that 11.1 has no issue deploying to Windows - it's just an Android issue.

What else do I need to do to migrate my code from Delphi 10.4.2 (API 29) to Delphi 11.1 (API 30)? I am not using any third-party libraries, just what comes with Delphi. Here is my uses statement in case that brings up any issues:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.UITypes, System.UIConsts, System.Classes, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls,
  FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.ListBox, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Edit, FMX.objects, FMX.Graphics,

{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  IdContext,IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, IdStack,IdIPWatch,
{$ENDIF}

{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  Androidapi.Helpers, Androidapi.JNIBridge, androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes, androidapi.JNI.Net,
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, 
{$ENDIF}

  FMX.ListView, FMX.ListView.Appearances, FMX.Grid, FMX.Memo,
  REST.Authenticator.Basic, REST.Authenticator.OAuth, REST.Client,
  FMX.ListView.Types, FMX.ListView.Adapters.Base, IPPeerClient,
  FMX.ScrollBox, FMX.Layouts, FMX.Controls.Presentation, System.Rtti,
  Data.Bind.Components, Data.Bind.ObjectScope, FMX.Grid.Style, REST.Types,
  FMX.Memo.Types
  ;
```

The Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.madmartian.SimpleHomeController"
    android:versionCode="41"
    android:versionName="41"
    android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
    <queries>

    </queries>
    <application
        android:persistent="False"
        android:restoreAnyVersion="False"
        android:label="SimpleHomeController"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:largeHeap="False"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
            android:label="SimpleHomeController"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="SimpleHomeController" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.rtl.notifications.NotificationAlarm" />

    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
```

Comment: By migrate, did you "upgrade" an existing project, or did you create a new project? If you did the former, you should do the latter instead. Always create a new project and add your existing sources to it as needed. Upgrading existing projects doesn't always work

Comment: As far as I know there were some changes regarding services in Android Delphi 11.1

Comment: If you have a service with your app, delete the .template.java files in the service project which will cause Delphi to recreate when you rebuild

Comment: *.template.java shows no files - unless there is a specific place to look other than the data folder or the SDK folder. I did upgrade an existing project. This has always worked in the past, sometimes with minor tweaks, but I can't get this to not crash. I even commented out the onformcreate contents and it still crashes.

Comment: So the Services thing is NA. I clicked on Remove Android Services and none are listed.

Comment: As much as I hate to admit it, Remy was right. I was spinning my wheels trying to fix the darn thing. Painstakingly recreated the UI in a new app (matching every setting on every control!) and copied the code over and it worked. There are some anomalies I still have to fix, but it doesn't crash at the splash screen. Embarcadero really needs to think about migration from old versions.